# Postgres Tunneling SSH -L In background

Tags: postgresql, ssh, tunnel

I'm trying to open an ssh connection to let one server access a remote postgres database. So I followed the instructions in this postgres [help page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/ssh-tunnels.html).

When I run the command:

```
ssh -L 3333:foo.com:5432 joe@foo.com
```

It connects me automatically to the remote server the same way it would with a regular ssh. At that point my connection works fine. The problem I'm facing is when I close the terminal, the connection is lost so I looked on how to run that same command in the background but with no luck. This is what I tried but it doesn't actually work:

```
nohup ssh -L 3333:foo.com:5432 joe@foo.com &
```

How can I run the ssh -L tunneling command in the background?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that `ssh -L 3333:localhost:5432 joe@foo.com` is the usual way, contrary to `ssh -L 3333:foo.com:5432 joe@foo.com` which generally leads to *Connection refused*. See a more recent version of the help page you linked to at: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ssh-tunnels.html which has been updated to explain this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After trying few options of ssh, I actually found the solution. Here it is:

```
ssh -f -N -L 3333:foo.com:5432 joe@foo.com
```

Comment: -f      Requests ssh to go to background just before command execution.